# Laravel 5 eloquent with whereHas more than 3. How to?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause, relation

it seems that it does not work, when I'm using  "with" and function inside it and later trying to use "has" function. Here's the code, it should be easier to understand:

```
$users = Users::where("active","=", "1")->with(['photos' => function($q){
            $q->where('type','!=', 2);
       }])->has('photos', '>', 3)->paginate(8);
}
```

It seems, that it should return user ONLY if he has 3 photos which are NOT of type 2. But it doesn't care about "where" clause and return it without checking to the type.

How can I achieve what I'm seeking?

Thank you!

Comment: Oh, and I have tried:
->whereHas('photos', function ($query) {
 $query->where('type', '!=', '2');
})   
but in this way I am not able ask for MORE than 3 photos. Because "whereHas" function checks if there is atleast 1...

Comment: `has` is the one that will check if there is at least 1. With `whereHas` you can use a `where` within its closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint on the eager loading of photos will not affect the query to get the users at all. You need to use the `whereHas()` method to add your `type` constraint to the photos check.

The `whereHas()` method is just syntactic sugar for calling the `has()` method with a callback properly. The `whereHas()` method also accepts an operator and a count. Therefore, the following should work:

```
$users = Users::with(['photos' => function($query) {
        $query->where('type', '!=', 2);
    }])
    ->where("active","=", "1")
    ->whereHas('photos', function ($query) {
        $query->where('type', '!=', 2);
    }, '>', 3)
    ->paginate(8);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was searching for. I have tried that "whereHas" but didn't know that it is possible to make "if more than N " because by default it was 1.

Comment: @Tautvydas No problem. When in doubt, you can always look at the source code, or check out the [api docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereHas).