# How can I make query for relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, many-to-many

I have a product table and a color table. And I have the following relation for them:

```
public function colors() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Color','product_colors');
}
```

I want to find out what product have more than 3 colors.
How can I do this?

Comment: Fetch colors, group them by product id, select groups that have more than 3 of them then fetch the products.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 eloquent with whereHas more than 3. How to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025233/laravel-5-eloquent-with-wherehas-more-than-3-how-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try simply with this :

```
$products = Product::has('colors', '>', 3)->get()
```

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accept the answer, and next time, use a better title for your question

Comment: May I ask, How can I get products that have the same 3 colors.
Sorry for so many questions but I am new with programing.

Comment: You can use `whereHas(function($query) { return $query->groupBy('id') }` and build your query according on what you want. I don't have the answer right now